# FPGA sync reset with filtering

Tags: fpga, reset

I have been reading about FPGA reset strategies. One thing that it appears all can agree on is that the reset release should be synchronous with the system clock. For reset assertion, the opinions are mixed with some in favor of asynchronous assertion while others favor synchronous assertion. The FPGA datasheet does not appear to provide any guidance either way based on HW features.

So, I have decided to implement a synchronous reset system for both assertion and de-assertion. However, I would like to inject a simple digital filter in the reset path that delays assertion and de-assertion, and does not allow the reset to change state until a "stable" signal is present.

I have attached a timing diagram along with some VHDL example code to show what I am planning. I would like an expert critical review of my plan along with feedback. Are there any hidden problems to look out for?

[image]

Comment: With synchronous assertion, if you clock is slow to start, your I/O states could be undefined and cause contention or undesired behavior. This is why asynchronous assertion is often used.

Comment: Put your actual code in the question, not a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for asynchronous assertion is that the reset works even if the clock is not running. If you have gated clocks, e.g. for power saving, your reset mechanism needs to *enable* clocks.

The main reason for synchronous deassertion is the timing relationship between the clock and the falling edge of the reset. But: that is only important if the first rising edge changes the state of the register.

Most logic stays in the reset state for a long time after the reset has been deasserted, because that is the state where it waits for the control state machine to activate it.

The only component where it matters is the control state machine itself. This has a reset state, and a state it enters on the first clock after that, and in this state it sends the first control signal to another component, which then has a full cycle to update its state, so timing here is safe.

Comment: On power up, system_reset is asserted by nature of setting the initial value of the signal to the reset state (1). So the power up condition with or without a clock shouldn't be an issue. The system doesn't even have a chance to have reset de-asserted until we have PLL Lock, which means the clock is ok. If we lose PLL lock, or power not valid, the reset circuit will force a reset after 8 clock cycles (sync). To your point, if the clock were to completely stop in between PLL lock being lost, and reset being asserted, then the reset would never be asserted. I believe this is a low probability.

Comment: @GregoryHelton, the initial value of the signal is ignored in most synthesis toolchains.

Comment: @GregoryHelton, also check that the PLL output is enabled while it is unlocked, a lot of PLLs have a gate, which would trigger exactly your "low probability" scenario.